# HTML5 Offline limitation of image sizes storage

Tags: local-storage, offline-caching, html5-appcache

I'm currently developing an application in HTML5 with the objective of providing users offline access the information. For this, use the technologies manifest appcache (files) and localStorage (data), performing data synchronization with my application in PHP + MySQL

In my scenario, where there is a register that has a list of images, I created a routine that generates the manifest.appcache (via PHP) with the list of images that need to be displayed in offline mode.
**The question is this: the sum of the size of these images passes from 60mb.**
Via Chrome (Desktop), this offline application that runs perfectly, but via Firefox, Android and iPhone smartphone does not work by the space limitation devices/browsers have for the cache manifest.

**The main question is:**
There is now the possibility of developing an HTML5 solution to address those needs?
I wondered the possibility of developing specific applications for Android and iPhone, but the goal was to have a platform independent solution.

---

**UPDATE:**
On my smartphone Defy MB525 with Cyanogemmod 7.1 NOT works (Firefox and Default browser).
But on Galaxy S3 of my friend with Android 4.0, works perfectly (Default browser and Chrome).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my tests and surveys, unfortunately there is a way to make this application work in HTML5 the limitations of devices and browsers.

I found the following page which details the limitations of various devices and browsers:
http://www.browserscope.org/user/tests/table/agt1YS1wcm9maWxlcnINCxIEVGVzdBjwwK0RDA?v=3&layout=simple

On the same page there is also an interesting link where you can test the storage limitation:
http://www.der-schepp.de/appcache-default-size/